# Maven override parent dependency with specific dependency

Tags: spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch, maven-3, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to override parent spring-data-elasticsearch dependency with specific one.
pom.xml:

```
    ...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    ...
    <dependencies>
    ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
```

with this configuration i have 7.17.6 elasticsearch in libraries. i need 7.12.1 When i change the version to higher or lower version nothing changes, but when i change the paren version to 2.5.2 the elasticsearch version in libraries become 7.12.1 . My question is: **How do i change the version of the dependecy without changing the parent version?**

I have tried to exclude the dependency with  tag but that didn't help me.

Comment: I would suggest to upgrade to most recent version of 2.7.x line of spring boot (2.7.7 https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/22/spring-boot-2-7-7-available-now) probably already upgraded there... or mabe upgrade spring boot 3.0.1 inclusive spring-data-elasticsearch to 5.0.1 ... what you can try to use `<properties><elasticsearch-rhlc>7.17.6</elasticsearch-rhlc></properties>` and retry that...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for replying. Unfortunatly spring-data-elasticsearch 5.0.1 is not compatible with my version of elastic. In stage/dev we have elastic and on prod we got opensearch in aws. The fork from elastic was made in version 7.10.2 so elasticsearch is compatible with opensearch only on that version. The data that elastic contains are about 5% of whole data and probably would not increase, we are ok with old version of spring-data-elasticsearch. John Williams version seems to work, so i will stick to it, but thanks for suggesion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [spring-data-elasticsearch/4.1.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch/4.1.1) is dependent on elasticsearch up to v7.17.8 (not v7.12.1)

To override the dependency to elasticsearch in the parent you should use the `dependencyManagement` tag, as follows to use elasticsearch v7.12.1.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>7.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Putting the dependency outside the dependencyManagement tag will work but is incorrect.